# 'int' object has no attribute 'append' with no real reason for this

Tags: python

I recently started learning the python language, and was completing my "homework", i found an error and i cant realy find any solution, i want to complete this homework by myself, so i am just asking why is the code giving such an error and does it have sense.

```
def matrix_creator():
    count1=0
    count2=0    
    count3=0
    lenght=4
    height=5
    arr_2d = [0]
    add_arr_2d = arr_2d[0]
    
    for count1 in range(lenght):
        for count2 in range(height):
            height+=1
            arr_2d.append([0])
        add_arr_2d.append(0)
        count1+=1
    arr_2d.pop(0)
    return arr_2d
```

The error is 'int' object has no attribute 'append', as well i am interested will it work

```
count = 0
arr_2d = [0]
add_arr_2d = arr_2d[count]
```

Comment: Double check what `add_arr_2d` is. It isn't a list as you're expecting. `arr_2d[0]` gets the first element of `arr_2d`, and `arr_2d` only contains a `0`.

Comment: Post the traceback message so we can see the exact error and line.

Comment: but the whole point is that the list creates in the                                                                                    for count1 in range(lenght):
    for count2 in range(height):
        height+=1
        arr_2d.append([0])
    add_arr_2d.append(0)
    count1+=1
arr_2d.pop(0)
return arr_2d

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-c9d68d2f480c> in <module>
----> 1 print(matrix_creator())

<ipython-input-4-016015e8be5d> in matrix_creator()
     12             height+=1
     13             arr_2d.append([0])
---> 14         add_arr_2d.append(0)
     15         count1+=1
     16     arr_2d.pop(0)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Did you mean for `add_arr_2d` to be a full copy of `arr_2d`? It isn't 100% clear what your intent is there.

Comment: i wanted to adress with the help of add_arr_2d to an element of arr_2d, for example arr_2d = [[0,1],[3,2]]
add_arr_2d = arr_2d[0] so with the help of add_arr_2d to adress to [0,1]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to create a 2D array (list of lists). Here is some sample code of how to do that:

```py
arr_2D = []
height = 7
length = 5

for i in range(height):
    arr_2D.append([]) #creates each row
    for j in range(length):
        arr_2D[i].append(0) #fills each element in the row
```

Answer (score 1):

Ther problem here is that when you initialize `add_arr_2d`, you set the initial value to the 0th value of `arr_2d`. This means that `add_arr_2d` is being set to 0 initially, making it an integer. To fix this, you can either cast `add_arr_2d` with a list:

```
add_arr_2d = list(arr_2d[0])
```

or cast it in brackets to make it an array:

```
add_arr_2d = [arr_2d[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you define `arr_2d` as a `list`:

```
arr_2d = [0]
```

Then you take the first element of the list `0` into `add_arr_2d`, so it will be an `int`:

```
add_arr_2d = arr_2d[0]
```

Later on you try to append to that integer, which cannot be done since integers are not lists:

```
add_arr_2d.append(0)
```